# SQL alter names - enum datatype..?

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

Basically I need to change the name of a field, from "aquire_method" to "acquire_method".
The thing is, it's an enum.

I read that I could use:

```
alter table "store_users_items" Change "aquire_method" "acquire_method" DATATYPEHERE;
```

So I did:

```
alter table "store_users_items" Change "aquire_method" "acquire_method" "enum('shop','trade','gift','admin','web')";
```

But it gives me syntax error. So how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax error could be because of using `"`

Try this:

```
alter table store_users_items Change aquire_method acquire_metho enum('shop','trade','gift','admin','web');
```

Comment: Oh I don't need to put it in quote tags?

Comment: Didn't work.


ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"store_users_items" Change "aquire_method" "acquire_method" enum('shop','trade',' at line 1

Comment: Please run the code I posted. your code is different from mine as it has double quotes yet

Comment: Oh, didn't notice you changed those as well, sorry, sec.

Comment: alter table 'store_users_items' Change 'aquire_method' 'acquired_metho' enum('shop','trade','gift','admin','web');

Gives syntax errors. :/

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''store_users_items' Change 'aquire_method' 'acquired_method' enum('shop','trade',' at line 1